# InvalidArgumentError: indices[82,0] = 69687 is not in [0, 69054)

Tags: python, keras, embedding, indices

I'm traing a four layer Deep Neural Network but I keep having this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: indices[82,0] = 69687 is not in [0, 69054)
     [[Node: user_emb_12/embedding_lookup = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@user_emb_12/embeddings"], validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](user_emb_12/embeddings/read, user_emb_12/Cast)]]
```

This is my code:

```
def EmbeddingRec(EMBEDDING_SIZE, Asin_Emb, NUM_USERS, ROW_COUNT):
    movie_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='asin')

    movie_emb = Embedding(input_dim=Asin_Emb, output_dim=EMBEDDING_SIZE, input_length=ROW_COUNT, name='movie_emb')(movie_input)
    movie_vec = Flatten(name='FlattenMovie')(movie_emb)

    movie_model = Model(inputs=movie_input, outputs=movie_vec)
    
    user_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='user_name')

    user_emb = Embedding( input_dim=NUM_USERS, output_dim=EMBEDDING_SIZE, input_length=ROW_COUNT, name='user_emb')(user_input)
    user_vec = Flatten(name='FlattenUser')(user_emb)

    user_model = Model(inputs=user_input, outputs=user_vec)
    
    merged = Dot(name = 'dot_product', normalize = True, axes = 2)([movie_emb, user_emb])
    merged_dropout = Dropout(0.2)(merged)
    
    
    dense_1 = Dense(70,name='FullyConnected-1')(merged)
    dropout_1 = Dropout(0.2,name='Dropout_1')(dense_1)

    dense_2 = Dense(50,name='FullyConnected-2')(dropout_1)
    dropout_2 = Dropout(0.2,name='Dropout_2')(dense_2)

    dense_3 = Dense(20,name='FullyConnected-3')(dropout_2)
    dropout_3 = Dropout(0.2,name='Dropout_3')(dense_3)

    dense_4 = Dense(10,name='FullyConnected-4', activation='relu')(dropout_3)
    
    flat = Flatten()(dense_4)  
    
    result = Dense(1, name='result', activation="relu") (flat)

  
    model = Model([movie_input, user_input], result)
    model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss= 'mean_absolute_error')
    return model, movie_model, user_model



EMBEDDING_SIZE = 10
Asin_Emb=len(all_ratings["asin"].unique()+1)
NUM_USERS=len(all_ratings["user_name"].unique())
ROW_COUNT = train.shape[0]


model, movie_model, user_model = EmbeddingRec(EMBEDDING_SIZE, Asin_Emb, NUM_USERS, ROW_COUNT)

history = model.fit([train.asin, train.user_name], train.stars, batch_size=2000,
                              epochs =10)
```

Comment: Which lines triggers the error ? I'm not familiar with keras, how is the embedding vocabulary size defined ?

Comment: The errors occur in the last line, in the model.fit, in keras the embedding vocabulary size is dafine as: "input_dim: Integer. Size of the vocabulary, i.e. maximum integer index + 1". For my project I took all of my product asin, plus 1

Comment: I think it should be obvious that your set vocabulary size is too small for the data, that is why you get the error.